# rails model doubts has_one, has_many, belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have created 3 models for a small system. The intent here is to handle users, companies and their relationships. I anticipate to do a lot of lookups over the intersections and also want to have strict controls over the joins available, in that a user can only belong to one company, but company can have many users. I feel the best way to represent this is with the below. I would like some feedback on this preposition. So far my tests have worked fine validating my thesis and some small implementation efforts have gone fine, but when I look through a list of users to find their company I somehow run into issues and I have a feeling it is related to the has_one relationship, but not sure. Again thanks for constructive feedback.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one  :companyrelationship, foreign_key: "user_id"
has_one  :company, :through => :companyrelationship, dependent: :destroy

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :companyrelationships
has_many :users, :through => :companyrelationships

class CompanyRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :user

validates :user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
validates :company_id, presence: true
```

Comment: What kind of issues you ran into?

Comment: Matzi, initially the issue I resolved was to use the right constructs for my tests (found this during has_one is required: user.build_companyrelationship..). However my challenge right now is that I lack experience in how to properly construct the controller actions so that when I create a company as a user, that the join table receives the required inserts. I see many discussion around adding this to forms, which seems poor solutioning to me, I would prefer to control this in the controller action of company create / new - ideas are welcome... The above post was also to elicit feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do see one thing that I'm pretty sure is an error and won't work. I can also try to add a couple points of constructive criticism.

The error is that the CamelCase model name is converted to underscorey (sorry, I can't remember the term for that right now) case. All your references to companyrelationship should add an underscore. You can override the convention by setting the :class_name attribute, but I don't think that's what you wanted.

Another issue I see which isn't technically wrong, but is almost certainly not what you want is that the `dependent: :destroy` would delete the `Company` when you deleted a `User`. (Actually, I'm not sure `dependent: :destroy` works in a `through:` relationship.) I assume what you wanted was just to delete the `CompanyRelationship`. You can read the section on *Dependent associations* at this link:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Next point is that the default `foreign_key` is the model + `_id` so you don't need to specify it in this case.

My last point is purely a style preference. I like doing my validations by validation type. You're doing them by variable. They are functionally equivalent, so feel to take it with a grain of salt. (I'm pretty sure `user` and `user_id` are equivalent, but feel free to stick to `user_id` if you're more comfortable with it.)

If it were completely up to me, I would code it this way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :company_relationship, dependent: :destroy
  has_one  :company, through: :company_relationship

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_relationships
  has_many :users, through: :company_relationships

class CompanyRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user, :company
  validates_uniqueness_of :user
```

I hope that helps you get further.

Comment: Geoff, just got back from a few days offline. Will look at your suggestion tomorrow, just wanted to thank you for posting...

Comment: Geoff, that was really great feedback, thanks for that. For some reason I still struggle with adding my records into my join table. In normal sql circumstances one could think that due to the relationships created, I should not need to code an addition to the join table on my crud actions in my company controller (thinking triggers), but I seem to need to do this. Is there no automation to be expected from rails when models are coupled as above? Apologies for the questions direction now, if you have a view I appreciate it.

Comment: I think you may be asking for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. You can read about it here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: If that's not what you were looking for, feel free to post a new question with specifics.

Comment: Geoff, thanks. I had looked at this, but deemed the need for a specific join model to be higher. My challenge is that with [associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), which are new to me. I find it very difficult to figure out how I syntax wise create a company and create the relationship join table entries in a company controller. I seem to find cases where due to the has_one for user I need to use user.build_company_relationship but for the has_many on company I don't. I am stuck on cracking the def new action on company.

Comment: I see that I need to apply a save on company to create the join model entry (otherwise no company.id), but how I add the join entry after the save confirmation I seem to be banging my head against, almost to simple... but apparently not for me right this moment.. thoughts are welcome - again appreciate the time taken to help

Comment: To get more precise this works, but I find it unattractive and what would happen in case where first save operation works but second fails..   `def create
    @company = Company.new(params[:company])
    if @company.save
      @companyrelationship = @company.company_relationships.build(user_id: current_user.id , company_id: @company.id)
      @companyrelationship.save`

Comment: When you save a model, it also saves any changes to its associations. Even better, it is done "transactionally" so you don't have worry about one working and one failing. In your case remove your current saves and just do @company.save at the end.

Comment: If you have any more questions, you should post a new question because I'm probably the only person who will see any new comments on this question.

Comment: by the way, it's referred to as snake_case